Scrolling under the element for RecyclerView
Maybe someone has encountered a problem when it is necessary to scroll through a vertical RecyclerView, but at the same time there is a fairly large element in the interface above it that has a click or touch listener. This element on top of it blocks scrolling of the list if you start dragging in its area. The element is located by design in such a place that the user often touches its area with his finger when starting scrolling. Maybe there is some solution so that the listener is end-to-end and does not block the scrolling events of the list. All other items on top of the list, to which the listeners are not linked, do not block anything.
I tried to put the element above the list IsEnabled = false and isClickable= false, but the focus does not go to RecyclerView and I have to repeatedly click in this area to start scrolling

Welcome to stackoverflow. Please read How to ask

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
